# how to install and configure phpcpp legacy module with phpv5.3.3 over centos 6.9

Tags: php, php-extension, php-cpp

Getting the error after installation and compiling phpcpp legacy version module with phpv5.3.3

> php -v
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/libphpcpp.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/libphpcpp.so: undefined symbol      : _ZN3Php9StreamBuf4syncEv in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2017 12:27:09)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: I have  followed the following reference guide : http://www.ttlsa.com/php/how-to-install-php-cpp/

Comment: did you add the extension to the php.ini file? and copy the libphpcpp.so file over to the correct directory?